# Revised: Is a question about the Economist's article "Silly Sausages" on topic, or are we too serious to enjoy a linguistic laugh?

Tags: discussion

This may be too funny to be the subject of a valid question, but see [*The Economist's* article *Silly Sausages*](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2019/06/29/europe-heroically-defends-itself-against-veggie-burgers) of June 29, 2019.

> **Silly sausages**
>
> **Europe heroically defends itself against veggie burgers**
>
> **And there are plenty more misleading words it should ban**
>
> THE EUROPEAN UNION gets a lot of flak. All right, it isn’t literally
>   blasted with anti-aircraft fire, but you know what we mean. One
>   ongoing battle (OK, nobody died) involves the use of words. Earlier
>   this year, the European Parliament’s agriculture committee voted to
>   prohibit the terms “burger”, “sausage”, “escalope” and “steak” to
>   describe products that do not contain any meat. It was inspired by the
>   European Court of Justice’s decision in 2017 to ban the use of “milk”,
>   “butter” and “cream” for non-dairy products. Exceptions were made for
>   “ice cream” and “almond milk”, but “soya milk” went down the drain,
>   lest consumers assume it had been extracted from the soya udder of a
>   soya cow. The court has yet to rule on the milk of human kindness.
>
> Greens are mounting a campaign against the committee’s decision, which
>   they suspect is supported not only by linguistic purists but also by
>   the meat industry. This newspaper thinks the parliament is quite right
>   to protect citizens from the confusion they would no doubt feel were
>   they to find that no part of a “veggie burger” was made of the flesh
>   of a dead animal. Indeed, this praiseworthy initiative needs to go
>   further.
>
> “Escalopes” pose a clear danger to consumers, who might well recoil in
>   horror when, taking a mouthful of one, they discover that it is made
>   not of the scallops from which it got its name but of chicken or veal.
>   “Sausages” should refer only to heavily salted meat, whence the term
>   derives; for clarity, consumers should be informed that the item is
>   encased in animal intestine. Steaks should be sold only on a pointed
>   stick, on the grounds that most shoppers will rely on the
>   proto-Indo-European etymology. Any confusion could be avoided if kebabs
>   were, as their Arabic root suggests, always sold burned. The
>   production of burgers should be restricted to the butchers of Hamburg,
>   long ago deprived of their intellectual property by a shocking failure
>   of linguistic regulation. The same right should be extended to makers
>   of Frankfurter sausages—sorry, meat-filled gut. And “meat” itself
>   should apply to all food, sweet or savoury, which would make the term
>   historically accurate, if useless.

Note:  See [Etomonline, steak](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=steak&source=ds_search) for the explanation why steak should be confined to meat served on a pointed stick.

The Economist article (link above) goes on to recommend reforming modern English to misunderstandings on budgetary vocabulary, for example:

> Discussion of computers should be limited to clerks who do budgetary
>   calculations, while that of the [digital single
>   market](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/infographs/ict/bloc-4.html)
>   should apply only to sums that people can do on their fingers.

The same article cites some geographical issues that need addressing to avoid confusion:

> ... the Mediterranean is not the centre of the Earth; there is no
>   horticulture in the Big Apple. They need renaming.

After a paragraph about the confusion that will result in the minds of readers when encountering "a level playing field" -- no, it is not a massive geoengineering project to move the Alps to fill in the low areas of Europe -- the Economist article concludes:

> The Treaty of Rome speaks of the need to respect member states’
>   culture (no, nothing to do with yogurt) and bind them together (please
>   put the string away). In view of those aspirations, Europe’s leaders
>   need to get on board with this reform. Not literally, obviously. It’s
>   not a ship. Never mind.

Anyone who thinks (s)he can summarize this article in their own words, and preserve its je ne sais quoi, please try! :)

**Now for the Meta Question:**  Is there a question here for the Main Site?  My thought is that there is a wider question here, which is Creeping Bureaucratese (CB).  Bureaucratese is a dialect of English, with many sub-dialects, even within a single country.  (To its credit, the US Internal Revenue Service website is pretty good at plain English, but the US Social Security site less so.)  **So the question might be, has CB ever been reversed, and if so, how?**

The narrow question might be, **did the EU embark on its linguistic reform on any evidence that consumers were confused by, e.g. soya milk?** (See article on the [German Agriculture Minister](https://www.foodnavigator.com/Article/2017/01/05/Silly-sausages-German-Ag-Minister-criticises-vegetarian-products-with-meaty-names)).

Finally, see the question of @Mari-Lou A on [almond milk](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/478302/is-it-technically-correct-to-call-an-almond-drink-milk-in-English), to which this Q is related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: I eagerly await the EU's realization that "hamburgers" contain no ham, and that "sausage" more often than not is bereft of sage. What do they propose to do about those highly misleading terms? (To say nothing of "hotdogs" and "hushpuppies.")

Comment: @Sven Yargs The Economist recommends: "The production of burgers should be restricted to the butchers of Hamburg, long ago deprived of their intellectual property by a shocking failure of linguistic regulation."  The Economist recommends linguist purity, going back in one case (steak)  to PIE.  Their tongue -- or anyway that thing that flaps in your mouth when you speak -- is firmly in their cheek.

Comment: Apropos of this discussion, a Twitter user recently made the following assertion: "Actually, it's only existentialism if it comes from the existentialism region of France. Otherwise, i's just sparkling anxiety."

Comment: @SvenYargs 'Hushpuppies' are given to the dogs to keep them quiet.

Comment: @SvenYargs [It's only a meme if it's from the Même region of France. Otherwise it's just not the same.](https://twitter.com/katemond/status/1143075400140120070)

Comment: Love the article, pity I can only read the first few paragraphs. I chuckled loudly :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA They offer free registration, including your choice of 5 articles. Nevermind that English only has 3.

Comment: @Lawrence ho ho ho I had to think for a few seconds before I got it :P

Comment: Yeah, there is a way to hit back: We have a vegetarian and a meat-eater go to an ice rink to hold a trial and use hocky sticks to fling the paties of our preferred variety at one another until somebody goes home with a broken crown. The  remaining combatant is declared the winner and declares what gets to be called a hamburger. How to hit back has nothing to do about language though, so that particular question would certainly be off-topic. There might be something else that can be asked though, if you care to elaborate.

Comment: I'm not sure why this ELU.Meta question is attracting votes to close on the basis of being generically off-topic. It's asking a question about whether to post "How do we hit back?" on ELU.Main. Now, *that* question might suit Politics.SE better, but *this* question about whether something is on-topic on Main is certainly on-topic on Meta.

Comment: @Lawrence I don't get it. What's the ELU.Main question? (Note: I can't access the Economist article)

Comment: @Mitch Article is a satire on the efforts of the EU to protect consumers from being confused about the food they are buying.  eg: “ 'soya milk' went down the drain, lest consumers assume it had been extracted from the soya udder of a soya cow."  Seriously. The Economist suggests that the EU is not being precise enough in its mandates.   "Steaks should be sold only on a pointed stick, on the grounds that most shoppers will rely on the proto-Indo-European etymology."  The Main Q would be how we, as sane language lovers fight the EU on this madness. Lawrence says that would be off topic. :)

Comment: Oh OK. Yeah sounds like fun. But a bit iffy (could go well, or could be reviled).

Comment: @ab2 What madness?

Comment: @curiousdannii it's one last hit at the EU before it's just chlorinated chicken and [cheap sins](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2019/jul/03/boris-johnson-cynical-sin-tax-freeze-glimpse-whats-to-come).

Comment: @Mitch The ELU Main question is “Can we hit back?” The Economist article talks about a movement to standardise the way food is named in the EU. One example ab2 picked up in comments above is *milk* - with a few exceptions, things called *milk* should actually come from a mammal at some point. He/she is asking whether the ELU community would mind a question pushing back on that naming policy.

Comment: @Lawrence he content of the question on main was unclear to me. Hit back at who? The Economist? The EU? The dairy industry? That's what was unclear to me in the short wording in the OP.

Comment: @Mitch I missed it on my first read through as well. At this point, the 'hitting back' is vaguely against whoever is trying to maintain etymological consistency. I'm sure there's a middle ground to be had - semantic drift and linguistic (mis)appropriation is part of the way the language has grown, but on the other hand, it doesn't seem right to label every misuse of the language as semantic drift in the making.

Comment: @Lawrence It _looks_ like milk.

Comment: @Mitch That's probably why it was so named.

Comment: This question just got bumped to the top. Reading it again, it's _still_ hard to understand what's going on here. Help us out. Give details about the Economist article. Give a link to the ELU.main question. etc etc.

Comment: @Mitch  I read a very funny article about  EU authorities being  persnickety about English, leading to bizarre re-naming of foodstuffs and thought others here would enjoy it.  I gave a link to the article, not realizing that for some reason the link would not work for some people.  If you can't access the article, it is beyond me to explain why it is so funny, short of copying the entire article into a Question.  "Hitting back" might be, for example. inundating the EU Ministry responsible with equally funny letters.  There is as yet no ELU main question.  I suggest we all move on.

Comment: @ab2 Can you add all that to your question here or, if you want that 'we all move on', then maybe you can remove this question?

Comment: @ab2 Sorry, I was a bit too harsh. This is a good kind of question to have, with answers that would show what the community would care about. But it still needs a lot of work to make it self contained. It's not clear what sausages and hitting back refer to. The edits you made did not clarify. Maybe instead for your meta-question, you could take a single example from the article and explain what the article says about the phrase, and then what it would mean for an ELU question to ask about that phrase. Note that on ELU, 'should' questions tend to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Mitch Oh, mitch. It was posted on meta because ab2 wanted to share a bit of fun with everyone. Sadly, experience tells me there can be no EL&U question, see my [almond milk question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/478302/is-it-technically-correct-to-call-an-almond-drink-milk-in-english), without someone thinking  it is a rant, patronising, confusing or plain wrong.

Comment: @ab2 Please do not delete the post,  I still love the introduction of the Economist article and I am terribly tempted to subscribe just so I can finish reading it. But their asking me for my email address and another password, is putting me off. Pity because the article is very witty.

Comment: Idea? Why not copy and paste the first page? What's there to lose? Unless you count some user finger-wagging about some copyright... as long as the author is mentioned and the source (which we already know) I see no problem. We have, in the past, seen encyclopedic answers here and on the main which seem never to end and were pretty joyless,  albeit extremely curated and informative, why not share some light heartedness? P.S Sven must have read the article, see his wry comment at the head of the pile.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  I'll get to it today, even if just for you.

Comment: Sigh, let us please not do that @MariLouA Aside from copyright, which is a valid enough concern, most university guidelines specify excessive quotation as a sort of plagiarism, and while I wouldn't always insist that we should follow university guidelines, I would at least insist that we follow our own: [Our referencing guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) do not only specify that we shouldn't copy whole external resources, but also restrict how much we may quote. There is some leeway to decide just how much that may be, but a whole page's worth is probably too much.

Comment: Those are good questions, and interesting if the context and source are also provided. No one will think of accusing it of plagiarism... with exceptions but they're clearly wrong.

Comment: Excellent... thanks @ab2 for making your meta-question self-contained and understandable. I realize that was extra work for you but that saves the work of every interested party from doing that same work over and over and over for each new person themselves. Your cut and paste was exactly what was needed, no sane person would ever consider that plagiarism because you are 1) quoting it 2) giving a reference to the original, and 3) using it as something to remark on as opposed to original work.

Comment: Now to content. There are rarely opinion based questions that don't get closed and the kind of question you're asking about sounds opinion based. A good non-opinion question is something like the one you link to of @Mari-LouA. But if a question is "What's wrong with the EU administration for forcing people to call non-greek feta, 'feta-like' when it's obviously feta". then that will probably be closed as to opinionated.

Answer (score 2):

No, it wouldn't be on-topic on Main, but I would welcome it anyway just this once.

Who knows, it might even make [greatest-hits](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits); no violence intended.